# Rounding Off numbers in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

```
<td colspan="3">
    <p class="text-left">
        <h5>Discount ( @php echo "- $subtotalquant"; @endphp  )</h5>
    </p>
</td>
<td>
    <p class="text-right">
        <h5>
            @php
                echo"&#8369;$subtotal";
            @endphp
        </h5>
    </p>
</td>
```

I wanted to round off the values into two decimal places. But number format doesn't seem to work.

It does look like this ^
[image]

```
$subtotal = 40.608

$subtotalquant = 10.152
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use Number format like this:

```
echo number_format((float)$subtotal, 2, '.', '');

echo number_format((float)$subtotalquant, 2, '.', '');
```

For more details you can see docs over here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: Glad to hear, If it solved your problem please close the question by accepting it.

Answer (score 17):

use like this, and also use the curly braces instead of echo.

```
{{round($subtotal, 2)}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{{ number_format($subtotal,2) }}
 {{ number_format($subtotalquant,2) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement this code in a blade file then use it like this:

```
{{number_format((float)$subtotal, 2, '.', '')}}

{{number_format((float)$subtotalquant, 2, '.', '')}}
```

Same thing if you want it in a PHP file then please follow the sagar's code.